# Yii2 : Yii::$app->request->baseUrl not working in Linux

Tags: php, linux, yii, yii2

its strange for me, I want to get base url in may main.php layout file. I put this code in my **main.php** file.

```
<?php var_dump(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl); ?>
```

**Output:**

```
string '/unfactory-v2/web' (length=17)
```

The same code when I execute in Linux system it's getting  empty. as like

```
string '' (length=0)
```

Why this is not working for Linux??

I'm  use Yii 2.

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 you can use:

```
Url::base()
```

or

```
Url::home()
```

or

```
Yii::$app->homeUrl
```

Even better, you can use path aliases (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/)

Comment: its getting same issue.

Comment: Then the problem is definitely server related, so the question should be moved to ServerFault ;)

Comment: I just flagged it, so that a moderator will check the thing ;)

Comment: yes! its worked. but I don't why its not worked for first time. lot of thanx@Masiorama.